# MFC dialog buttons show up as black boxes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, user-interface, mfc

I have an old MFC utility written with VS2008 project. We have used this utility for a few years now and I have never experienced this problem personalty but it is showing up more and more often on customers computers.

Sub dialogs launched from my main dialog will have their buttons blackened out. I have included a screenshot from one of my customers computers.

[image]
<sub>(source: [chipkin.com](http://chipkin.com/files/dialogboxerror.png))</sub>

The customer is using Microsoft Windows XP Professional Version 2002 Service Pack 3. I have tested this problem with this version of Windows in our lab with out being able to reproduce it. This problem has happened on lots of different peoples computers.

Do you know what causes it? and how to resolve it?

Comment: I have seen this problem, and I'm trying for the life of me to remember what it was...

Comment: Is there anything 'interesting' about these buttons? Do they have bitmaps?  Owner-drawn?  Use a custom CButton-derived class?  Does your dialog handle WM_CTLCOLOR to change the color of the buttons?

Comment: @John Dibling, No there is nothing special about these buttons. I changed there default names and thats about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this when the machine was out of memory. It didn't have enough RAM left to load the button images.

Comment: Not out of memory - just out of GDI handles. Usually happens if there's a GDI leak somewhere. The chance of that happening are much higher than being out of memory.